# Subscribe to Observable in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a function, which remembers a previous url

```
   prevId () {
     let name, id, lat, lng;
    this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe(e => {
        console.log('prev:', this.previousUrl);
        this.previousUrl = (e as NavigationEnd).url;
    }
```

I would like to rewrite this in Observable-style, if it possible, but everything I try doesn't work. 
Is it possible to solve?
Could you also please advice me some good articles about Observable, because I am just beginner and the topic seems to be pretty difficult.

UPD: I need to usr the data outside the function later, that is why I need Observer.

for example

```
myFun(a) {
console.log(a);
}

myFun(this.previousUrl);
```

Comment: But you are using Observable

Comment: @Giovane ok...So, I need to return some value, to use it outside the function...is it possible?

Comment: Now we'r having some important details haha, Update the question explaining what you'd like to do.

Comment: What value do you want to return ?

Comment: @HugoNoro  this.previousUrl

Comment: OK, in that case do you have the previousUrl declared somewhere on your component?

Comment: @HugoNoro yes, it is a public value

Comment: In that case from the moment you set it in the subscribe it will update your variable. Not sure what you’re problem is. Is this code not being called? Maybe edit the post with a bit more code to make it easier to understand

Comment: @HugoNoro I added a little example, which shows how the data should be used later

Comment: If the previousUrl is a property of the component you don’t need to pass is as parameter. It’s available in the state. You just need to do this.previousUrl inside the myFun function.

Comment: @HugoNoro in this case, if I use it in this way the value is undefined

Comment: Well of course that will depend on the sequence of calls you’re doing. You need to do the call to the subscribe on the constructor. If you’re using angular 5 router events are no longer available on ngInit. You have to do it in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you need is use the url outside of your function, you may do this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

prevId(): Observable<NavigationEnd> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    this.router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .take(1)
      .subscribe(e => {
        observer.next(e as NavigationEnd);
        observer.complete();
      });
  });
}
```

Then you must call the function like this:

```
prevId().subscribe(navigationEndEvent => {
  this.previousUrl = navigationEndEvent.url;
});
```

I made this example thinking that you just want the previousUrl information when you call the `prevId()`, because of this I put the `.take(1)` operator and called `observer.complete()`.
The `.take(1)` will automatically unsubscribe the subscription made into `this.router.event` when the first value comes from it.
And the `observer.complete()` will also unsubscribe the all the subscriptions made whenever in the returned Observable.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried the example, provided by your, but as I try to call prevId().subscribe, compiler tells me that propery 'subscribe doesn't exists on type 'void' '...

Comment: Are you returning the `new Observer(...`?

Comment: @AnnaF take a look at this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-observable-treatment My code works fine, take a look.